# "Undefined" problem when receiving data from api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, undefined

I'm improving myself on reactjs. I'm trying to build an e-commerce site. I use Mock Api as a service. I can list my data in ProductList.js. but I can't call the same data in ProductDetails.js. I'm getting an "undefined" error.

```
const ProductDetail = (props) => {
    const { buttonLabel, className } = props;
    const { name, description, price,id } = props;
    const axios = require('axios');

    const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);

    const toggle = () => setModal(!modal);
    const [dress, setDress] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get(`https://5fd9d76f6cf2e7001737ead3.mockapi.io/api/v1/dress`)
            .then(function (response) {
                setDress(response.data);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }, []);
    const data = dress.map(item => {
        return {    
            name: item.name,
            description: item.description,
            price:item.price,
            id: item.id       
        }
    })
        return (
            <div >
                <ProductDetailButton onClick={toggle}>Detay{buttonLabel}</ProductDetailButton>
                <Modal isOpen={modal} toggle={toggle} key={`${data.id}`} className={className}>
                    <ModalHeader toggle={toggle}>{`${data.name}`}</ModalHeader>
                    <ModalBody >
                    {`${data.price}`}
                    </ModalBody>
                    <ModalBody>
                    {`${data.description}`}
                    </ModalBody>
                    <ModalFooter>
                        <Button color="secondary" onClick={toggle}>
                            Kapat
                        </Button>
                    </ModalFooter>
                </Modal>
            </div>
        );
```

Modal is displayed as output. It says "undefined" instead of data. How to fix it?

Comment: `data` is an array of objects, so I suspect your issue is that you're not treating it like an array in your returned JSX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your api returns an array of objects, so if you have a ProductList, you should not do the api call in Product Details. You should pass the items as props.

Example.

```
const ProductList = () => {
       const [showProduct, setShowProduct] = useState(null)
 ..... api call and data...

return (
    <React.Fragment>
          {data?.map(item => <div>{item.name} <button onClick={() => setShowProduct(item)}> Show Item </button> </div> }

        { !!showProduct && <ProductDetails item={showProduct} onClose={() => setShowProduct(null) /> } //this will open up your modal

    </React.Fragment>
)

}
```

then in your product details it should be something like.

```
const ProductDetails = ({ item, onClose }) => {
//your item details accessible here via props

    return <Modal> <ModalBody> {item.name} </ModalBody><ModalFooter><Button onClick={onClose}>Close</ModalFooter></Modal>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your code `const data` value will be changed. But rerender will not happen as its not in state. Another issue is `data` is an array (map returns an array). In order to call like `{data.name}`  data should be an object.

Put `data` in state

```
useState(()=> {

    const data = Array.isArray(dress) && dress.map(item => {
        return {    
            name: item.name,
            description: item.description,
            price:item.price,
            id: item.id       
        }
    }
// set the state
setData(data);

}, [dress]);
```